# Shading artifacts in a low poly mesh

Tags: modeling, artifacts

Can somebody describe the technology for getting rid of artifacts like these. I moved around some vertices and added/removed some edges, reset and smoothed normals, added weighted normal modifier, which did improve things, but some of the issues are still there:

[image: mesh]

I don't see anything seriously wrong with the mesh. Or is it perhaps something that you just have to live with in low poly meshes? Like I said, I am perhaps more interested in the general technology and approaches for dealing with issues like these, not necessarily fixing this particular mesh (although that would be nice too).

[image]

Comment: In general you won't have good smooth shading with low poly meshes, unless you bake a normal map from a subdivided mesh

Comment: ... maybe you could improve the quad-flow across that surface .. share it on https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Hello could you please share your so that we give it a test? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Blend file added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to smooth the shading, Blender creates a gradient between your triangles. Your triangles are a bit disorganized, thereofre this bad shading. Simplify the topology, work with quads and the shading will be less chaotic (here, a quickly made topology):

[image]

Sometimes tris are OK, for example these ones won't cause any problem:

[image]

Comment: So basically the approach you suggest is to use quads no matter how small or insignificant they might seem? Also, when redesigning the mesh, did you only redo the polys or you also had to move vertices laterally to alter the surface relief?

Comment: I just dissolved some edges to only keep quads, and moved some edges. Tris are sometimes OK, but here they caused problems, I could have kept some without problem though

Comment: @NebehrGudahtt, What do you mean by "no matter how small or insignificant they might seem"?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys, in the example above, if the goal is to strictly use quads, there should be a really narrow and unnecessary quad between the polys indicated with green arrows. As moonboots later explained, in some cases tris are acceptable though.